# Why does the author mean to say this? "If Mr. Erdogan loses, Turkey will be a difficult ally with a difficult future."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does he/she mean to say, without a stronger president, it would be hard for the EU to deal with Turkey since the country is in turmoil?

**Turkey will remain pivotal after April 16th. *If Mr Erdogan loses, Turkey will be a difficult ally with a difficult future.* But if he wins, he will be able to govern as an elected dictator.**

*The Economist, April 15, 2017, Turkey is sliding into dictatorship*
http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21720590-recep-tayyip-erdogan-carrying-out-harshest-crackdown-decades-west-must-not-abandon

Comment: No. They mean that if the referendum does not result in the new system striven for by Erdogan, the future of Turkey will be unclear and therefore difficult. This is a problem since an uncertain future in a turmoil-stricken country is not what you want if this country is your (military) ally.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I don't clearly understand what you mean by "the new system striven for by Erdogan." I would appreciate if you would  give me more explanation.

Comment: I could also have said, "the new system wanted by Erdogan". I'm referring to the constitutional referendum that, if approved, will replace the current parliamentary system with a presidential system.

Comment: But if he loses, there would be no changes in the constitution. Am I right?

Comment: If I got the whole affair right, that's correct, yes.

Answer (score 2):

The [Turkish Constitutional Referendum of 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_constitutional_referendum,_2017) is a vote to determine whether [18 proposed amendments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_constitutional_referendum,_2017#Constitutional_amendments) to the Turkish constitution should be implemented.

The author of the article you reference thinks this is a bad idea, and lists several reasons.

The quote really needs the conjoining 'but' to make sense:

> If Mr Erdogan loses, Turkey will be a difficult ally with a difficult future. But if he wins, he will be able to govern as an elected dictator.

This says that if Mr. Erdogan loses, Turkey will (still) be a difficult ally to have, and Turkey will (still) have a difficult time ahead. But if Mr. Erdogan wins, then (according to the author) this will be a political disaster for Turkey (Erdogan will become a dictator).

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thank you very much.